# How to creat a symbolic link to all files with a specific extension from a specific directory using a shell script?

Tags: scripts

I tried the following code, but I'm missing something somewhere. I want to create a symbolic link to all *.conf files from /etc/ in /root/links

```
#!/bin/bash

for conf in /etc/
do
    ln -s "$conf" "/root/links/$conf"
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you mean:

```
for conf in /etc/*.conf
do
    ln -s "$conf" /root/links/
done
```

?

Comment: Yes. this is what I was looking for.